# Missing attachment type in Outlook Addin BeforeAttachmentAddEventHandler

Tags: c#, outlook-addin

I have an Outlook AddIn that handles attachments. I have installed a handler to catch attachments before they are added so that I have a chance to process them.

The following code use to work but has stopped because the atttachment type form files that have been dragged into the email is 0.

```
void handleBeforeAttachmentAdd(Outlook.Attachment attachment, ref bool cancel)
        {


            try { 

                Outlook.OlAttachmentType type = attachment.Type;

                TDAddIn.log(String.Format("handleBeforeAttachmentAdd type : {0}",   type));
                if ((attachment.Type == Outlook.OlAttachmentType.olByValue)  && TDAddIn.canAddAttachment(true))
                {
                    // Do something
                }
            }

            catch (System.Exception exception)
            {
               // handl exception
            }

            return;

        }
```

Does anybody know what has happened here and how I can handle it?

Barry

Comment: My Outlook version is 2002 Build: 12527.20278

Comment: Did you mean Outlook 2016? That sounds like a bug.

Comment: It is Outlook for Office 365 MSO (10.0.12527.20260)64 Bit part of the MS Office 365 Home subscription.

Comment: Do you mean **16**.0?

Comment: Sorry,Yes it is 16.0.12527.20260

Comment: I can reproduce this problem in version 16.0.12527.20260 as well as in 16.0.12624.20224.

Comment: What is the best way to report a bug in Outlook so that it has a chance of getting fixed?

I reported this via their support center but have heard nothing back so I have no idea if anything is being done.

Comment: According to an Outlook PM, a fix is already checked in. They do not know yet which update exactly will include the fix.

Comment: This bug seems to still be in the current version of Outlook 16.0.13029.20342. It looks like from this that it has acually been around fo a while: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/940ebe46-04d6-4daf-80c5-1bd26ace5e12/catching-event-attachmentadd-sometimes-results-in-quotcannot-create-attachmentsquot-in-outlook?forum=vsto. Is there a known workaround?

Comment: According to an Outlook PM, the bug is still open, but it is being worked on. There is no ETA yet.

Comment: According to the PM, the fix will be in build 13513.10000 or later. That build should be in Insiders/Beta the next week or so and CC in late December or January

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Dmitry has found, this seems to be an Outlook bug.

Answer (score 0):

To work around this Outlook bug you can add an attachmentAdd() handler and perform the same thing you would do in the handleBeforeAttachmentAdd() but in place of setting the 'cancel' parameter to true you call attachment.Delete() to remove the original attachment.

```
void handleAttachmentAdd(Outlook.Attachment attachment)
{
            string tempFile = System.IO.Path.GetTempFileName();;
            try
            {

                if (attachment.Type == Outlook.OlAttachmentType.olByValue))
                {                       
                     attachment.SaveAsFile(tempFile);

                    if (MyAddIn.attachFile(tempFile, attachment.DisplayName))
                    {
                        attachment.Delete(); // Delete the original attachment
                    }                        
                }
            }

            catch (System.Exception exception)
            {
                // handle exception
            } 
            System.IO.File.Delete(tempFile);
}
```